# Sorting a list of objects containing a list java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to sort the following class:

```
public class Request {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<RequestType> requestTypes;
}

public class RequestType {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private RequestTypeEnum requestTypeEnum;
    private long date;
    private boolean done;
    private int priority;
    private String id;
}
```

The request class needs to be ordered based on the data from the requestTypes property.  How would I go about approaching this problem

I started by doing nested for loops:

```
 for(int i= 0;  i< requests.size(); i++) {
        Request request = requests.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < request.getRequestTypes().size();j++) {

        }

    }
```

Not sure what I need to do from there it needs to be ordered by the date field in ascending order.

Comment: Maybe looking at the Documentation site, and this example: [Sorting a List using Comparable<T> or a Comparator<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/3137/comparable-and-comparator/10693/sorting-a-list-using-comparablet-or-a-comparatort) will give a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Simply use `Collections.sort(...)`, passing in the requestTypes list, and an appropriate Comparator.

Comment: `requestTypes.sort(Comparator.comparing(RequestType::getDate));`

Comment: You first need to refine your requirements. Each request has 0 to N request types, each having a date. So you need to define how to sort: basd on the lowest date in the lists, on the greater date, on something else? What if a request has no request type, and thus no date?

Comment: it requires atleast one requesttype or else a request won't exist.